# VBA to copy specific data from multiple workbooks into this master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code on a master sheet when I press a button it goes though the folder that I want and opens and closes the sheets where it should extract data from.

The problem is how to extract the data from the sheets (suuplier timesheets) it opens and put it into the next free row and specific columns in the master sheet.

Here is the code I have for opening and closing the files from the button on the master sheet. I need a code for the space ###CODE GOES HERE

```
Public Sub test()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Path = "\\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\CSV Supplier Main\Inbox folder\"  'CHANGE PATH
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    '
    ' ###CODE GOES HERE
    '


   wbk.Close True
   Filename = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

In the sheets that the macro above is opening the data will only be copied if cell L12 has a value.
Then there are specific cells with the data. Below is my crude attempt. I also need this to go to the next line for where there is a value in L13 copy the data as well. (Think a loop Until L23):

```
isMyCellEmpty = IsEmpty(Range("L12"))
        If isMyCellEmpty = False Then
L3T_Supplier_number = Range("J8")
L3T_Purchase_Order_number = Range("J9")
GL_code = Range("L12")
Supplier_Hours1 = Range("I12")
```

Here is the pasting in the master sheet. my crude attempt. Before this you need to go to the next free row in column A. Then the direction below.

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = L3T_Supplier_number
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = L3T_Purchase_Order_number
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = GL_code
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Supplier_Hours1
```

Can you please write the code for me that can get the data from the sheets that are opening and past this into the master sheet where the macro is held.

Let me know if any questions. I have trying to do this for a while with no progress. Need someone to come to the rescue.

Comment: Don't think there's enough information there. What precisely are you having trouble with?

Comment: so I have the macro that goes through all the files in the folder. But I do not know how to place into this the macro that would copy the data from the sheet the macro opens to the sheet where the macro runs. There are specific data that needs to be copied.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].